# How can I determine which element's attribute needs to be modified?

Tags: html, asp.net, css, razor, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to visually clean up the appearance of a legacy asp.net page; it seems that something has a border-left and border-right property that I need to get rid of, but I can't determine which element it is that I need to target. Here is what the problematic area looks like:

[image]

I want to get rid of the vertical lines to the left and right of all labels ("Begin Date", "End Date", "Begin Time" and "End Time"); I want to keep the border surrounding the whole shebang, but not the inner borders/lines.

When I right-click directly on the vertical line to the left of the "End Date" label and select "Inspect Element," Chrome Developer Tools highlights the <td> that hosts the "EndDate" label. If I deselect the "border-left" property in the CSS, a portion of the vertical line at the *far left* disappears, but that's not the one I want to get rid of - I want to get rid of the vertical line *immediately* to the left, not the one at the far left. Similar things happen when trying to get rid of the next vertical line to the right.

Here's what Chrome Developer Tools shows me:

[image]

Here is the html:

```
<div class="fieldsetbox" style="width: 640px;">
    <table style="border: none; border-collapse: collapse; table-layout: fixed;">
        <colgroup>
            <col style="width: 40px;" />
        </colgroup>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LabelDateRange)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="trBeginDate">
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BeginDate)
            </td>
            <td style="padding-right: 20px;">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BeginDate, new {alt = "date-us", style = "width: 109px;"})
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BeginTime)
            </td>
            <td style="padding-right: 20px;">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BeginTime, new {style = "width: 109px;"})
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr id="trEndDate">
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EndDate)
            </td>
            <td style="padding-right: 20px;">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EndDate, new {alt = "date-us", style = "width: 109px;"})
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EndTime)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EndTime, new {style = "width: 109px;"})
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="trDateValidation1">
            <td>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.BeginDate)
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.BeginTime)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="trDateValidation2">
            <td>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EndDate)
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EndTime)
            </td>
        </tr>
```

I feel somewhat like the immortialized spider on a promontory seeking to connect the spheres, but not knowing where to attach my filaments.

### UPDATE

Following the trail recommended by "vals," I found that there is no "fieldsetbox col" in the entire solution...

However, I did find:

```
    .fieldsetbox
    {
        margin: 2em 0;
        padding: 0 1em 1em 1em;
        background: #F9F9F9 url('/@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationHome"]/Content/wp-
```

content/themes/infocus/images/form-gradient.gif') repeat-x scroll 0 -7px;
            border: 2px solid #E0E0E0;
        }

...So I commented out the last line (border) but, alas, no change is effected.

### UPDATE 2

All of the "border-right" strings I found in the project were in telerik and jquery-ui css files.

Also, there's one in Site.css for elements with an index of "main"

I hit the jackpot with the cshtml file, though:

I commented out *all* of the "border-left" and "border-right" properties in there, namely for:

```
#trSalesTotal td
#trBeginDate td
#trEndDate td, #trDateValidation1 td
#trDateValidation2 td
```

...and now I get this:

[image]

So, I got a little overzealous there; will have to figure out how to retain the vertical lines on the far ends...time to go to the Experimentation Station...

Comment: It's a little hard without having access to the css file, but I would also check the first column for a `border-right` property.

Comment: Understood, but especially the CSS situation is a mess: external, internal, and inline CSS is used. Lions and Tigers and Bears, oh my!

Comment: Have you checked the cols ?

Comment: @vals: Meaning? I see no cols in the CDT representation...

Comment: At the beginning of the table, you have a colgroup with a col. (Width 40px in the inline style). That could allow some CSS in the line of ".fieldsetbox col" or "fieldsetbox colgroup" that would be difficult to spot thru the dev tools. Just guessing, anyway ...

Comment: Thanks, aisle czech that out.